# How to find the tangential and normal components of the acceleration?

Tags: calculus, multivariable-calculus, vector-spaces, vector-analysis

How can I find the tangential and normal components of the acceleration vector at $t=2$ for: $r(t)= t\mathbf{i} + \displaystyle\frac{t^2-1}{2}\mathbf{j} + \displaystyle\frac{t^2+1}{2}\mathbf{k}$

I found the velocity vector at $t=2$ to be $\langle1,2,2\rangle$
and acceleration vector to be $\langle1,0,1\rangle$

What goes next for the tangential and normal components of acceleration vector?

Comment: Is that all the information you have ?  What have you tried ?

Comment: so tangential acceleration seems like = V dot A / magnitude of V, so I dot product the acceleration and velocity the divide by magnitude of V which is 3. Am I right? The answer seems to be 1 for tangential acceleration

Comment: You are almost there. See answer posted by Onomnomnom

Comment: I fixed my question. Somehow it wouldn't recgonize vectors so I put it in i,j,k format.

Comment: yep so I am getting 1 for both tangential and normal components.  I hope I am right

Answer (score 1):

The tangential component of $\vec a$ is given by
$$
a_{tan} = \frac{\vec a \cdot \vec v}{\|\vec v\|}
$$
The normal component is given by 
$$
a_{norm} = \left\|\vec a - \frac{a_{tan}}{\|\vec v\|}\vec v \right\|
$$

Comment: So I am getting an answer of 1 for both tangential and normal acceleration components. Am I right? 

I updated my question earlier, the main function wouldn't show which was: t=2 for: r(t)= t i + (t^2-1)/2 j + (t^2+1)/2 k or < t , (t^2 - 1)/2 , (t^2 + 1)/2 >

Comment: It looks like you're getting the right answer to me.

Comment: okay thank you so much! Thought so.